# Display button on Woocommerce variable product when no price is set for variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Some products on the site cannot be purchased directly so I've replaced "Add to Cart" with a custom button that links to a custom WooCommerce tab on a product page containing an Enquiry Form.

This was done by using `woocommerce_empty_price_html` filter. When the product has no price set -> Display a button.

However, my solution works only on Simple Products and I need it to work on Variable products as well.

This is my code that works for Simple product:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_price');

function custom_call_for_price() {
    $ccfp .= '<a class="switchtab" href="#tab-quick_quote"><button type="submit" id="trigger_cf" class="quote-button single_add_to_cart_button button alt" >Quick Quote</button></a>';
    ?><script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("a.switchtab").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div.woocommerce-tabs>ul.tabs>li>a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").click();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("div.woocommerce-tabs").offset().top
        }, 500);
    });

});
    </script><?php

    return $ccfp;
}
```

When I switch my product to a Variable product, default WooCommerce behavior is to hide variations with no prices. So I tried to override that with

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_is_visible', 'product_variation_always_shown', 10, 2);
function product_variation_always_shown($is_visible, $id){
    return true;
}
```

This resulted in having the button displayed for variable product with no price for variation, but the problem is that I'm seeing "Add to Cart" button and my "Quick Quote" button now behaves like Add to cart(instead of scrolling to anchor) with a message

> "Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different
>   combination."

To display it graphically, this is what I currently have on my variable product.

[image]

I need that the variable product with no price acts as my example for a simple product with no price. To hide the "Add to Cart" form and displays a button that scrolls to tab, but still to allow users to select an option because I'm passing the option value to an inquiry form.

Can this be done for a variable product?

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?